# pyspark read excel with some empty column names

Tags: excel, pyspark

I have an excel in which some of the column names are empty. How it is possible for the pyspark to read them?

I tried with this code but it reads only the columns which have names:

```
df_xls=sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("startingRow", 2) \
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true") \
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
    .load(download_path)
```